# Ansible cannot install Chocolatey Packages using UNC Choco source

Tags: windows, ansible, chocolatey

`Ansible Version: 2.4.2.0`

`Ansible Control: Centos7`

`Target Hosts: Windows 2012R2`

I have a File Server named: `FILESERVER` and I have placed all `chocolatey` packages in folder `C:\Packages`. And this folder is shared, so other servers can access this folder via UNC path: `\\FILESERVER\Packages`.

If I login to one of the machines and run:

```
choco install 7zip -y -s \\FILESERVER\Packages
```

it goes ahead to that file server and installs the package. However, if I try this via `Ansible` it says the package does not exists in Choco Source.

```
---
- hosts: win
  tasks:
    - name: chocolatey-core.extension
      win_chocolatey:
        name: chocolatey-core.extension
        state: present
        source: \\FILESERVER\Packages
```

Error:

```
fatal: [mdb]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "choco_error_cmd": "choco.exe install -r --no-progress -y chocolatey-core.extension --timeout 2700 --failonunfound --source \\\\FILESERVER\\Packages", "choco_error_log": ["Installing the following packages:", "chocolatey-core.extension", "By installing you accept licenses for the packages.", "chocolatey-core.extension not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.", " Source(s): '\\\\FILESERVER\\Packages'", " NOTE: When you specify explicit sources, it overrides default sources.", "If the package version is a prerelease and you didn't specify `--pre`,", " the package may not be found.", "Please see http s://chocolatey.org/docs/troubleshooting for more ", " assistance.", "","Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.", " See the log for details (C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\logs\\chocolatey.log).", "", "Failures", " - chocolatey-core.extension - chocolatey-coree.extension not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.", " Source(s): '\\\\FILESERVER\\Packages'", " NOTE: When you specify explicit sources, it overrides default sources.", "If the package version is a prerelease and you didn't specify `--pre `,", " the package may not be found.", "Please see https://chocolatey.org/docs/troubleshooting for more ", " assistance."], "command": "choco.exe install -r --no-progress -y chocolatey-core.extension --timeout 2700 --failonunfound --source \\\\FILESERVER\\Packages", "msg": "Error installing package 'chocolatey-core.extension'", "rc": 1, "stdout": "Installing the following packages:\r\nchocolatey-core.extension\r\nBy installing you accept licenses for the packages.\r\nchocolatey-core.extension not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.\r\n Source(s): \\\\FILESERVER\\Packages'\r\n NOTE: When you specify explicit sources, it overrides default sources.\r\nIf the package version is a prerelease and you didn't specify `--pre`,\r\n the package may not be found.\r\nPlease see https://chocolatey.org/docs/troubleshooting for more \r\n assistance.\r\n\r\nChocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.\r\n See the log for details (C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\logs\\chocolatey.log).\r\n\r\nFailures\r\n - chocolatey-core.extension - chocolatey-core.extension not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.\r\n Source(s): '\\\\FILESERVER\\Packages'\r\n NOTE: When you specify explicit sources, it overrides default sources.\r\nIf the package version is a prerelease and you didn't specify `--pre`,\r\n the package may not be found.\r\nPlease see https://chocolatey.org/docs/troubleshooting for more \r\n assistance.\r\n", "stdout_lines": ["Installing the following packages:", "chocolatey-core.extension", "By installing you accept licenses for the packages.", "chocolatey-core.extension not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.", " Source(s): '\\\\FILESERVER\\Packages'", " NOTE: When you specify explicit sources, it overrides default sources.", "If the package version is a prerelease and you didn't specify `--pre`,", " the package may not be found.", "Please see https://chocolatey.org/docs/troubleshooting for more ", " assistance.", "","Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.", " See the log for details (C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\logs\\chocolatey.log).", "", "Failures", " - chocolatey-core.extension - chocolatey-core.extension not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.", " Source(s): '\\\\FILESERVER\\Packages'", " NOTE: When you specify explicit sources, it overrides default sources.", "If the package version is a prerelease and you didn't specify `--pre`,", " the package may not be found.", "Please see https://chocolatey.org/docs/troubleshooting for more ", " assistance."]}
```

I am not sure if the ansible error message is confusing with `\\\\Fileserver\\Package` UNC path? or is it actually using that `\\\\FileServer\\Packages` as actualy Choco Source?

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that ansible via WinRM cannot access the net share because it runs in a different context.

See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_winrm.html#limitations for limitations.